# Django - считается ли нормальным хранить функцию во views.py среди View классов?

Tags: python, django, best-practice

Всем привет, хочу узнать мнение людей с опытом: есть 9 классов и среди них затерялась одна функция, считается ли нормальным хранить эту функцию  во `views.py` среди based Views классов? Или стоит ее вынести в другой файл, например в `services.py`?

Вот код функции (она работает с ajax запросом)

```
def add_favourite(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        id = int(request.POST.get('advertisementId'))
        advertisement = get_object_or_404(Advertisement, id=id)
        if advertisement.favourites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            advertisement.favourites.remove(request.user)
        else:
            advertisement.favourites.add(request.user)
        total_favourites = Advertisement.objects.get(id=id).total_favourites
        return JsonResponse({'total_favourites': total_favourites})
```

Или может эту функцию можно переделать в class based Views ?

Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: А почему бы и не переделать в CBV? Раз вы говорите, что это единственная функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по хорошему, раз у вас везде CBV, то и эту вьюху надо тоже в CBV переделать. И сделать это очень просто

```
from django.что-то.там import View
from django.что-то.там import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class AddFavourite(View):
    
    def post(self, request):
        id = int(request.POST.get('advertisementId'))
        advertisement = get_object_or_404(Advertisement, id=id)
        if advertisement.favourites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            advertisement.favourites.remove(request.user)
        else:
            advertisement.favourites.add(request.user)
        total_favourites = Advertisement.objects.get(id=id).total_favourites
        return JsonResponse({'total_favourites': total_favourites})
```

Comment: спасибо за совет, так и сделаю) P.S. можете пожалуйста объяснить что нам дает строка `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')`. Прочитал в документации про @method_decorator но не совсем понял что он дает

Comment: каждая вьюха имеет метод dispatch, в котором происходит выбор метода которому нужно передать запрос. каждый POST запрос маркируется csrf токеном, чтобы ваш ajax запрос заработал, если он отправляется методом POST,  вам нужно либо предоставить csrf токен, что не сложно если отрабатываете со страницы либо отключить проверку декоратором csrf_exempt. т.е. проще говоря мы отключаем проверку csrf токена для AddFavourite.

Comment: теперь всё понял, еще раз спасибо)